# CakePHP save two models, second based on first

Tags: cakephp, model, save

I have the following association:

Group hasAndBelongsToMany User, with the groups_users join table.

When I create a new group, I want to add to the join table the founder of the group.

My $this->data array looks like:

```
Array
     (
[Group] => Array
    (
        [name] => seyufgsduifsj
        [access] => 2
        [founder_id] => 3
        [random_key] => I6XC7uMTelpTSdq8DbtLPjqubiF7s6Pn
    )

[GroupsUser] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 3
        [group_role_id] => 1
        [random_key] => PZsDZXcoCTHw1IuvqsfURVpPX6AcZ3r2
    )
```

)

I tried with save() and saveAll(), but it would add only the group in the groups table and not the user-group association.

So, basically, I have an add form where the user fills in the group name and access. Then, if the data validates, I add a couple of more field values to the group array (like random_key) and to the join table array (like user_id and group_role_id). I want Cake to save the group first, take its id, update the join table array with the proper group_id, and then save this second array too.

Is this possible in a straight-forward way, or do I have to write two consequent save() methods, for the second one providing the last inserted id in the first one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the related models are not passing validation. Use the following piece of code to save **only if all models validate**:

```
$this->Group->saveAll($this->data, array('validate' => 'only'));
```

If you don't find your Group being saved this time around, then it's most probably validation rules in your Join Model that are failing. My guess is that you have a `notEmpty` validation for the `group_id`, which you would have to remove in order for saveAll() to work.

Hope this points you in the direction of solving your problem.

---

**EDIT:** Your associations are a little off. Here's what it should be:

```
Group hasMany GroupsUser
User hasMany GroupsUser
GroupRole hasMany GroupsUser
GroupsUser belongsTo Group
GroupsUser belongsTo User
GroupsUser belongsTo GroupRole
```

Remove the `hasAndBelongsToMany` association between Groups and User. It doesn't exist any more.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and probably it won't save because of a validation error within the join model. Having this in mind, I erased all validation settings from the join model, and **still** the data is not saved.

Comment: Why change the HABTM relationship to multiple hasMany - belongsTo? Isn't HABTM meant for these situations?

Comment: Quoting from the book: "It is sometimes desirable to store additional data with a many to many association." At this point you need to use a hasMany Through, and not a HABTM relationship. http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together#hasMany-through-The-Join-Model-1650

Comment: OK, I'll try hasMany Through then. And when I save the group together with the owner I will do the same, `$this->Group->save()`?

Comment: Use `saveAll()` to save related models.

Answer (score 3):

You can use saveAll() function, but you need to change the format of the GroupsUser array. According to documentation of [saveAll()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/75/Saving-Your-Data) your data should look like this:

```
Array
     (
[Group] => Array
    (
        [name] => seyufgsduifsj
        [access] => 2
        [founder_id] => 3
        [random_key] => I6XC7uMTelpTSdq8DbtLPjqubiF7s6Pn
    )

[GroupsUser] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
               [user_id] => 3
               [group_role_id] => 1
               [random_key] => PZsDZXcoCTHw1IuvqsfURVpPX6AcZ3r2
            )
    )
)
```

Your example would work if the relation is **Group belongsTo GroupsUser**, but I believe this is not your case

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my relation is GroupsUser belongsTo Group, as GroupsUser is the HABTM join table. Anyway, I have already tried your solution and it saved only the group.